# \blockquote outputting unpredictably

Tags: biblatex, formatting, csquotes

I am writing a thesis in Overleaf in which I am using a lot of quotations. To output these nicely I decided to use the `\blockquote` command from `\usepackage{csquotes}` as follows:

```
 {\footnotesize\blockquote[\citet{source}]{quote} \par }
```

This almost always outputs the same nice looking quotation, except for some cases where the blockquote does not stand out from the text.

Here is a working example with SC of output. The wrong output is the middle quotation, which outputs incorrectly regardless of where I place it in the text.

```
    \documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{paper}
    
    \usepackage[natbib=true, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
    \begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
     @article{Kanlantari2018,
    author = {Kanlantari, Fatemeh},
    year = {2018}
    }
    @article{Benke2017,
    author = {Benke, K and Tomkins, B},
    year = {2017}
    }
    @article{Al-chalabi2015,
    author = {Al-chalabi, Malek},
    year = {2015}
    }
    \end{filecontents*}
    \bibliography{database.bib}
    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    {\footnotesize \blockquote[\citet{Kanlantari2018}]{As the world population continues to grow at a rapid rate, accompanied by a substantial
    growth in food demand which is expected to transpire in the next 50 years, 80\% of the population will be living in urban areas} \par }
    
    {\footnotesize \blockquote[\citet{Al-chalabi2015}]{It is predicted that the world population will reach 9 billion by 2050, of which 70\% will live in urban centres.}\par }
    
    {\footnotesize \blockquote[\citet{Benke2017}]{The unremitting trends of increasing population, urbanization, diminishing water supply, and continuing climate change have contributed to declining stocks of arable land per person. }\par }
    \lipsum[2]
    \printbibliography
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

There are a couple of quotations in my document that have an weird output and  I am looking for what I am doing wrong.

Any brute force fixes are also welcome, I have not succeeded with simple `\vspace` and `\hspace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `csquotes` documentation explains the `\blockquote` command as follows

> `\blockquote[<cite>][<punct>]{<text>}<tpunct>`
> This command determines the length of the `<text>`. If the length exceeds a certain
> threshold, the `<text>` will be typeset in display mode, i.e., as a block quotation. If not, `\blockquote` will behave like `\textquote`.

[image: screenshot of documentation with the quoted text from above]

So the result is easily explained by the fact that the second quotation does not exceed the set threshold while the first and third do. (The default settings check if the text is longer than three lines if typeset.)

You can set `threshold` to zero to make `\blockquote` always come out as a block quotation. Surprisingly there is no option to disable the `threshold` testing or no dedicated "always block-quote" command in `csquotes`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[threshold=0]{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbib=true, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
{\footnotesize \blockquote[\citet{sigfridsson}]{As the world population continues to grow at a rapid rate, accompanied by a substantial
growth in food demand which is expected to transpire in the next 50 years, 80\% of the population will be living in urban areas} \par }

{\footnotesize \blockquote[\citet{sigfridsson}]{It is predicted that the world population will reach 9 billion by 2050, of which 70\% will live in urban centres.}\par }

{\footnotesize \blockquote[\citet{sigfridsson}]{The unremitting trends of increasing population, urbanization, diminishing water supply, and continuing climate change have contributed to declining stocks of arable land per person. }\par }
\lipsum[2]


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: all three quotes formatted as block quotes]

It might be more elegant to have `csquotes` add the `\footnotesize` automatically. For citations you can also look into using `\blockcquote`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[threshold=0]{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbib=true, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{footnotesizequote}
  {\quote\footnotesize}
  {\endquote}

\SetBlockEnvironment{footnotesizequote}

\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\blockcquote{sigfridsson}{As the world population continues to grow at a rapid rate, accompanied by a substantial
growth in food demand which is expected to transpire in the next 50 years, 80\% of the population will be living in urban areas}

\blockcquote{sigfridsson}{It is predicted that the world population will reach 9 billion by 2050, of which 70\% will live in urban centres.}

\blockquote[\citet{sigfridsson}]{The unremitting trends of increasing population, urbanization, diminishing water supply, and continuing climate change have contributed to declining stocks of arable land per person.}


\lipsum[2]

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: all three quotes formatted as block quotes]

Just in case it is useful, here is a definition of a `\blokcquote`-like command that does not do any `threshold` testing and always defaults to the block quote styling.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbib=true, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\bblockquote}{%
  \csq@getcargs{\bblockquote@i{}{}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\bblockcquote}{%
  \csq@getccargs{\bblockquote@i{}{}}}

\def\bblockquote@i#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \csq@getpunct{\csq@bquote@iii{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{footnotesizequote}
  {\quote\footnotesize}
  {\endquote}

\SetBlockEnvironment{footnotesizequote}

\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}


\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\bblockcquote{sigfridsson}{As the world population continues to grow at a rapid rate, accompanied by a substantial
growth in food demand which is expected to transpire in the next 50 years, 80\% of the population will be living in urban areas}

\bblockquote[\citet{sigfridsson}]{It is predicted that the world population will reach 9 billion by 2050, of which 70\% will live in urban centres.}

\bblockcquote{sigfridsson}{The unremitting trends of increasing population, urbanization, diminishing water supply, and continuing climate change have contributed to declining stocks of arable land per person.}


\lipsum[2]

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly :)